Help me to get an upper bound for $x$ if $x$ satisfies some condition related to $f(x)=(1+x+\frac{x^2}{3})e^{-x}$

My problem is the following. Let $f$ be the function defined on $\mathbb{R^+}$ such that $f(x)=(1+x+\frac{x^2}{3})e^{-x}$. Given $a, b>0$, and $0 < c < 1$, and $x > 0$ satisfying $$f\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)\leq c\leq f\left(\frac{a}{x}\right),$$
I want to get bounds for $x$ in terms of $a, b, c$.

The easiest solution would be to use $f^{-1}$ (which exists since $f$ is decreasing) to get $\frac{a}{f^{-1}(c)}\leq x\leq\frac{b}{f^{-1}(c)}$. Alas, $f^{-1}$ has no closed form, and I would like to get explicit bounds, so another approach is needed.
The lower bound $f\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)$ can be handled quite easily ; since the quadratic term is bigger than $1$, the exponential part can be used as a lower bound, and it's simple to solve for $x$. The upper bound, however, is troublesome : we need to bound $f\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)$ from above by something easily invertible and lower than $1$. I couldn't find anything, any ideas ?

It is not clear what you are asking. For $x \ge -1$ it is easy to get $f(x) < 1$.

Indeed, $f(x)<1$ for any $x>0$. What I'm asking for is an expression of $x$ between $f\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)$ and $1$ that could be inverted to get a bound for $x$.

Can you use the Lambert W function in the final expression?

I omit the construction for now...
I considered functions of the form $$H(a;c) = \frac{a}{a+e^{-1/x + cx}}$$ for some $c \in [0,1]$ and $a>0$. By choosing a suitable $a$ and $c$ we get a function which is bounded below by $f$. The inverse is given by $$H^{-1}(a; c) = \frac{\ln(a/x -a)}{2c} + \sqrt{\frac{\ln(a/x -a)^2}{4c^2} +\frac{1}{c}}$$ and found for example that $H(20; 0.9)$ is bounded below by your function $f$.
Hence $$x \mapsto \frac{20}{20+e^{-1/x + 0.9x}}$$ defines an injective function $B:\mathbb{R}^+_0  \to \mathbb{R}^+_0 $ with $$ f(x) = e^{-x}(x^2/3+x+1) \le B(x) \le 1\qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+_0 \\ B^{-1}(x) = \frac{10 \ln(20/x -20)}{18} + \sqrt{25 \frac{\ln(20/x -20)^2}{81} +\frac{10}{9}}~.$$
